# Input question being asked multiple times because of multiple IF statements - Loop never closes(edited)

Tags: python, input

I'm new into python and I'm  trying to understand how everything works together. I'm trying to write a script that prints different messages depending on the user input. because I defined the question in a function, I figured that it gets printed for each if statement until it reaches the correct answer. I was wondering how can I do this to print the question only once and then, based on the user input, to show the correct line.

Using the variable, the loop never closes if I input "4"

```
def quest2():
    q2 = input("\nWhat's your prefered beverage? \n\t1. Beer \n\t2. Wine \n\t3. Vodka \n\t4. I don't drink alcohool (Answer with: 1, 2, 3 or 4)")
    return q2

variable1 = quest2()

while True:

    if variable1 == "1":
        print("\nYou went the safe route")
        break
    if variable1 == "2":
        print("\nSomeone has some fine taste")
        break
    if variable1 == "3":
        print("\nYou build your own stuff")
        break
    else:
        print("\nStop lying, everyone drinks, I'll give you another chance to change your answer")
        continue
```

Comment: Assigning the function result to a variable is the solution.  We need to see *that* attempt in order to help you, rather than this version which cannot possibly work (because you're actually calling the function up to three times).

Comment: after doing that, the while loop never closes and it runs over and over , without asking for the input again.

Comment: Why would you expect it to ask for input again?  You only do that once, before entering the loop.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to understand, how to not break the loop if a specific input is selected. in this example, if 4 is selected, the question to run again, to somehow "force" the user to choose from 1-3. I believe that my code is wrong, something that I didn't understand.

Comment: You need `if/elif/elif/else` instead of `if/if/if/else`.  Also you need to assign `variable1 = quest2()` **inside** the loop, so that the user has a chance to enter another answer.

Comment: that's great. I got it. I didn't understand very well how it worked but now it makes sense. really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to assign value for the question, then use that value.

```
def quest2():
    q2 = input(
        "\nWhat's your prefered beverage? \n\t1. Beer \n\t2. Wine \n\t3. Vodka \n\t4. I don't drink alcohool (Answer with: 1, 2, 3 or 4)")
    return q2

while True:
    question = quest2() # Call question once here and assign result for it for later check.
    if question == "1": # No need to call another question.
        print("\nYou went the safe route")
        break
    if question == "2": # No need to call another question.
        print("\nSomeone has some fine taste")
        break
    if question == "3": # No need to call another question.
        print("\nYou build your own stuff")
        break
    if question == "4":
        print("\nOk")
        break
    else:
        print("\nStop lying, everyone drinks, I'll give you another chance to change your answer")
        continue
```

Comment: I used that script but now I'm having issues when I input 4, because the loop runs without stopping and asking the question again

Comment: You have to check if user input value 4 then break the loop. I edited the answer above so that when you enter 4, the loop stop.

Comment: I saw that an answer for "4" was added. my idea was that when input == 4, then the question will run again, as a way to rethink the answer, I'm guessing that's something that can't be done? because in the code above, the else runs only if it's something different from 1-4

Comment: So you want to question your user until he/she input 1-2-3? If that is the case, then you just have to put the quest2 method inside the loop like i did.